# Receiving multicast inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, sockets, multicast

I have the following python script that runs inside my docker container.

```
addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo(MYADDR, None)[0]

# Create a socket
s = socket.socket(addrinfo[0], socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Allow multiple copies of this program on one machine
# (not strictly needed)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Bind it to the port
s.bind(('', MYPORT))

group_bin = socket.inet_pton(addrinfo[0], addrinfo[4][0])
# Join group
if addrinfo[0] == socket.AF_INET: # IPv4
  mreq = group_bin + struct.pack('=I', socket.INADDR_ANY)
  s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)


while 1:
    try:
        print("receiving")
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(4096)
    except socket.error as e:
        pass
    else:
        print(f"From: {addr}")
        print(f"Data: {data}")
```

The script works fine on the host machine, it receives data from the multicast every couple seconds.

When I run the image like this I don't receive anything

```
docker run my_image python myscript.py myaddr myport
```

Even if I use the host network I don't get any traffic.

```
docker run --network host my_image python myscript.py myaddr myport
```

I don't want to use the host network because I want to run the script from docker compose and have it write to a database on a bridge network.

```
build:
  context: ./backend
environment:
  - POSTGRES_HOST=db
command: python myscript.py myaddr myport
networks:
  -backend
depends_on:
  - db
```

Also my host machine is windows 10 and docker container is ubuntu:18.04

Comment: Try `network_mode: "host"` to use the host's network.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for the response but as I mentioned I ran the with the command --network host and it did not work.

Comment: Have you been able to figure out this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.